# ICollectionView not applying SortDescription

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light, observablecollection, collectionview

This is a WPF MVVM-light app.

A quick note: `UserList`, used in the `GetDefaultView`, is an `ObservableCollection<T>`

I have a collection view that is built like so:

```
private ICollectionView _iCollectionUserList { get; set; }
    public ICollectionView ICollectionUserList
    {
        get
        {
            if (_iCollectionUserList == null)
            {
                _iCollectionUserList = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(UserList);
                _iCollectionUserList .SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("StatusID", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
                _iCollectionUserList .SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("EmployeeNo", ListSortDirection.Ascending));
            }
            return _iCollectionUserList ;
        }
    }
```

It will sort by `StatusID`, but it absolutely refuses to sort by `EmployeeNo`.  I cross referenced my query in SQL Server MGMTS with my app and it definitely is not working.  I tried commenting out the `StatusID` sort and that doesn't work either.  Both are of type `int`.

Comment: Property names are case sensitive. Can you cross check property name?

Comment: if you remove EmployeeNo sort line, does it work?

Comment: Yes.  It works right now with it, it just doesn't do that specific sort.

Comment: could you post a sample your source data and sorted output?

Comment: I actually figured it out todat.  I just called .Refresh () on it.